# Ballerina with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ballerina

I am struggling to get Ballerina working with Visual Studio Code (on Windows 10). 
It is installed and works fine from Command Prompt, however it cannot complete build command in Visual Studio Code. It does not seem to be able to finish build command effected via Visual Studio Code. I have Ballerina extension for Visual Studio Code installed. 
Does anybody had similar problems and know how to overcome it? 
Bellow please find details of versions:

Ballerina 1.2.1
Language specification 2020R1
Ballerina tool 0.8.5

VSC:
1.44.2
Ballerina extension for Visual Studio Code

Windows: 
10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362

Answer (score 0):

@GregorSind, try quitting the VSCode instance and then reopen. This might be that the environment variables are not being visible to the VSCode instance. Also, check what's the integrated shell of VSCode

Comment: Thanks for answer, it has not worked for me thoug. Luckily the have released 1.2.2 and new plugin for Intellij so I have switched to that.